# Fill a triangle with nodes on the corners

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, fill

I'm drawing three nodes and connecting them to a triangle:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [ circle, draw ] (A) at ( 1, 0) {A};
        \node [ circle, draw ] (B) at (-1, 0) {B};
        \node [ circle, draw ] (C) at ( 0, 1) {C};
        \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A);
            % Bonus question: Why doesn't cycle work here?
        \fill [black] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But filling the triangle didn't work! I want the area enclosed by the triangle filled, excluding the node circles. (I can't just extract the coordinates and fill the triangle defined by that, it would paint over the nodes.)

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked before, though it might not be easy to  search for.  You need to specify an anchor of the nodes for that to work, e.g. `A.east`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I searched, but couldn't find anything :/ I would be surprised if I'm the first one to ask this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nodes are extended objects, that's why `cycle` does not work, but it works once you specify the anchors, as pointed out by Torbjørn T..

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [ circle, draw,fill=white ] (A) at ( 1, 0) {A};
        \node [ circle, draw,fill=white ] (B) at (-1, 0) {B};
        \node [ circle, draw,fill=white ] (C) at ( 0, 1) {C};
        \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A);
            % Bonus question: Why doesn't cycle work here?
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]  
        \fill [black] (A.center) -- (B.center) -- (C.center) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

- Clipping instead of filling the circle nodes with white.
- Blue circle lines.
- Red connection lines.
- Triangle filled with green.

Issues:

- The triangle can be filled with a simple:

  ```
  \fill (A.center) -- (B.center) -- (C.center) -- cycle;
  ```

  The clipping region is defined by
  the full current drawing area
  minus the circle areas using the even odd filling rule.

  The radii can be calculated via TikZ library `calc`.
- There can be background pixels between the circle lines and the filled area due to rounding issues.

  Therefore, the circle raddii are made a little smaller, the effect of using `outer sep=0pt` for the nodes. But `outer sep=0pt` cannot
  be used because of the connection lines that would stick into the circle lines.

  The filled triangle is put on the background layer, thus the overlapping part
  is covered by the circle lines.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[every node/.style={circle, draw=blue}]
      (1, 0) node (A) {A}
      (-1, 0) node (B) {B}
      (0, 1) node (C) {C}
    ;
    \draw[red] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A);
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \begin{scope}{even odd rule}
      \clip
        (current bounding box.south west)
        rectangle (current bounding box.north east)
        let
          \p{A} := ($(A.north) - (A.center)$),
          \p{B} := ($(B.north) - (B.center)$),
          \p{C} := ($(C.north) - (C.center)$)
        in
          (A) circle[radius=\y{A}-.5\pgflinewidth]
          (B) circle[radius=\y{B}-.5\pgflinewidth]
          (C) circle[radius=\y{C}-.5\pgflinewidth]
      ;
      \fill [green] (A.center) -- (B.center) -- (C.center) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Without colors, the example can be simplified:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[every node/.style={circle, draw}]
      (1, 0) node (A) {A}
      (-1, 0) node (B) {B}
      (0, 1) node (C) {C}
    ;
    % \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A);
    \begin{scope}{even odd rule}
      \clip
        (current bounding box.south west)
        rectangle (current bounding box.north east)
        let
          \p{A} := ($(A.north) - (A.center)$),
          \p{B} := ($(B.north) - (B.center)$),
          \p{C} := ($(C.north) - (C.center)$)
        in
          (A) circle[radius=\y{A}-.5\pgflinewidth]
          (B) circle[radius=\y{B}-.5\pgflinewidth]
          (C) circle[radius=\y{C}-.5\pgflinewidth]
      ;
      \fill (A.center) -- (B.center) -- (C.center) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result, black version]

BTW, `cycle` needs points, not nodes, see the `\fill` command in the examples above.